# Assembly count A,B,C,a,b,c

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I am writing a assembly program to count the number of uppercase A,B,C and lowercase a,b,c. The issue I am running into is the program not going to the label if the comparison is correct. I have tried storing the char in registry but the same thing keeps on occurring.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void readData(), readChar(), printData();
int i = 0, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
char ch;
string str;

int main()
{
    _asm
    {
        call readData;
    whileloop:
        call readChar;
        cmp i, 10;
        je done;
        jne toLoop;

    toLoop:
        cmp ch, 'A';
        je addA;
        cmp ch, 'B';
        je addB;
        cmp ch, 'C';
        je addC;

        cmp ch, 'a';
        je addA;
        cmp ch, 'b';
        je addB;
        cmp ch, 'c';
        je addC;

    addA:
        inc a;
        jmp whileloop;
    addB:
        inc b;
        jmp whileloop;
    addC:
        inc c;
        jmp whileloop;
    done:
        call printData;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void readData()
{
    cout << "Enter the sentence: ";
    cin >> str;
}

void readChar()
{
    ch = str[i];
    i++;
}

void printData()
{
    cout << "A = " << a << "\nB = " << b << "\nC = " << c << endl;
}
```

Comment: `ch` is a singularly bad choice for a variable, since it is also a register name. Presumably the assembler recognized it as a register. Rename it. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Really... I have debugged the program and it seems to store the character in ch. ummm maybe at the cmp statement it checks the registry.

Comment: @Nignig: Just change the name to prevent the clash of names...